# Simulate HealthKit Data on WatchOS for Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos, healthkit

I am setting up my first WatchOS App. I simply want develop a little App for an Apple Watch that for the start only displays the Heartbeat.

I have writte a function that does so and now I would like to test if it works as expected with the **Simulator** but I cant find any way or source in the web that explains how to do so. (ChatGPT says its not possible but I dont believe so)

With Android its simple, there you can just set a value for the Heartbeat, e.g. 100, in the Android Studio UI or send an ADB command. This command then will send an Event of the particular type. This makes it easy to validate that my app is listening to the correct event and does what it should :)

Is there something similar in Xcode/Simulator? I would really appreciate some guidance.

(And if its really not possible as ChatGPT says, how are developers then testing the functionality?)